# Getting Started with vServers

Tags: debian, linux-vserver

Sorry to ask a newby question, but do documents describing the first steps with a Debian vServer exist on the Internet?

Any kind of tutorial-like documentation for absolute beginners would also suffice.

Comment: n00by? interwebz?

Comment: Are you fixed to use Linux-Vserver or do you want information about virtualization on Linux in general?

Comment: Oh, Linux in general is fine. Sorry, the question was a bit unclar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [**this**](http://linux-vserver.org/Installation_on_Debian) which appears to be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can as well take a look at [openvz](http://wiki.openvz.org/Main_Page) - another 'lightweight' almost-virtualgizaiton solution.